# Mass/light ratio of galaxies

Tags: galaxies

I'm really stuck. I need to figure out the mass/light ratio of a galaxy in solar units. I know its mass is 5.7 x 10<sup>10</sup> solar masses. I know its absolute magnitude (-17.3) and distance (29 Mpc). I'm feeling dumb here because I think this ought to be clear to me, but I'm getting hung up at the magnitude - luminosity - light part.

Here's what I think:
mass/light = 10<sup>0.4*(Magnitude galaxy-magnitude Sun)</sup> x (mass galaxy/mass Sun)

I get a mass to light ratio of around 90. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the result is about 80 (unit: solar mass per solar intensity).

Taking "light" as meaning [intensity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_%28physics%29) (measured from Earth in units of power per unit area) the ratio, $R$, is:

$ R = \frac{m_g}{I_g} = \frac{5.7 \times 10^{10} m_{sun}}{I_g \times \frac{I_{sun}}{I_{sun}}} = \frac{5.7 \times 10^{10} m_{sun}}{\frac{I_g}{I_{sun}} \times I_{sun}} $

where $m_g$ is the mass of the galaxy, $I_g$ is the intensity of the galaxy and $I_{sun}$ is the intensity of the Sun.

$ \frac{I_g}{I_{sun}} $ can be computed from:

$ M_g - M_{sun} = -2.5\log_{10} ( \frac{I_g}{I_{sun}} ) $

where M are magnitudes.

Rearranging and using a value of [4.83 for the absolute magnitude of the Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun):

$ \frac{I_g}{I_{sun}} = 10^{-0.4(M_g - M_{sun})} = 10^{-0.4(-17.3 - 4.83)} = 7.1 \times 10^8$

Inserting $ \frac{I_g}{I_{sun}} $:

$ R = \frac{5.7 \times 10^{10} m_{sun}}{7.1 \times 10^8I_{sun}} = 80\ \frac{m_{sun}}{I_{sun}} $

Comment: Thanks!  I worked it a few different ways and kept coming up with the same figure.  It was the number that worried me since I believe that most galaxies are between 10 - 50 and galaxy clusters are 100-200.  But thats the number (80) I'm sticking with!

Comment: @Gigi Giles: no problem. Now to the 'accept' phase :-)